# How to do Free Monad-like stuff with TypesScript?

Tags: typescript

I recall getting walked through someone's Haskell codebase and being really intrigued when I saw the that the type definitions for every API handler explained exactly all of the side-effects invoked by the function. So I've set out to try to accomplish a similar thing with TypeScript. Here's what I have so far.

```
export type More = {
    then: (...args: any[]) => Thenable
}

type Done = {
    then: undefined
}

const done = { then: undefined } as Done

type Thenable = More | Done

type RedisRead<Key extends string, Then extends Thenable> = {
    type: "RedisRead"
    key: Key
    then: (value: string) => Then
}

type RedisWrite<Key extends string, Then extends Thenable> = {
    type: "RedisWrite"
    key: Key
    value: string
    then: () => Then
}

function readRedis<Key extends string, Then extends Thenable>(
    key: Key,
    then: (value: string) => Then
): RedisRead<Key, Then> {
    return {
        type: "RedisRead",
        key: key,
        then: then,
    }
}

function writeRedis<Key extends string, Then extends Thenable>(
    key: Key,
    value: string,
    then: () => Then
): RedisWrite<Key, Then> {
    return {
        type: "RedisWrite",
        key: key,
        value: value,
        then: then,
    }
}

// Inferred type: RedisRead<"x", RedisWrite<"y", Done>>
function doSomething() {
    return readRedis("x", value => {
        return writeRedis("y", value, () => {
            return done
        })
    })
}
```

The result of the code above is that `doSomething` has an inferred type of `RedisRead<"x", RedisWrite<"y", Done>>`. Pretty neat right!

We're not quite finished though. I want to write an interpreter that can interpret this language. It should look something like this:

```
type Language = Done | RedisRead<any, Language> | RedisWrite<any, Language>

function interpret(item: Language) {
    if (item.type === "Done") {
        console.log("Done")
    } else if (item.type === "RedisWrite") {
        redis.add(key, value, () => interpret(item.then()))
    } else if (item.type === "RedisRead") {
        redis.get(key, (value) => interpret(item.then(value)))
    }
}
```

However, TypeScript is mad that I have a recursive type definition for Language. That's a bummer . Any way of getting around this?

The next thing I want to be able to do is use the ES6 async / await syntax by extending Promises. Its messy, but I've come up with a way to extend Promises.

```
class RedisRead<Key extends string, T extends Promise<any>> extends Promise<
    string
> {
    resolve: (value: any) => void
    reject: (value: any) => void
    constructor(public key: Key) {
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            this.resolve = resolve
            this.reject = reject
        })
    }
    type: "RedisRead"
    then: (fn?: null | ((value: string) => T)) => T
}

class RedisWrite<Key extends string, T extends Promise<any>> extends Promise<
    string
> {
    resolve: (value: any) => void
    reject: (value: any) => void
    constructor(public key: Key, public value: string) {
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            this.resolve = resolve
            this.reject = reject
        })
    }
    type: "RedisWrite"
    then: (fn?: null | ((value: any) => T)) => T
}




async function doSomething() {
    const value = await new RedisRead("x")
    return new RedisWrite("y", value)
}
```

It appears to work, but the inferred type is `Promise<any>`

Anyways, I think this architecture would be really powerful. Please let me know if you can figure out a way around these issues.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the [existing work on monads in TypeScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+monad)?  It's likely to be much better than anything I can hack together for you right now.  Note that async/await syntax assumes that a given promise returns at most once, so it will only work for monads with that property, e.g., the maybe monad and typical side effect monads but not the list monad.